# Powershell function doesnt work after restart?

Tags: function, powershell

My functions work fine before restart but not after. Why?

Code:

```
Function import-cloud {
    Robocopy "C:\Users\sonde\2021sky" "C:\Users\sonde\Skrivebord\2021lokal" /MIR
}
Function export-cloud { 
    Robocopy "C:\Users\sonde\Skrivebord\2021lokal" "C:\Users\sonde\2021sky" /MIR
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6zUt.png)

Comment: Did you define them again after restarting? The `function` keyword only associates the scriptblock with the function name _in the current session/shell_ - they're gone as soon as you exit

Comment: if you want them to be permanent then you must define them in the [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmdlets or Functions are not loaded normally during Powershell startup.

On start:

1. Powershell loads descriptors of modules from `$env:PSModulePath` directory to be ready to internally call `import-module` when you try to use CmdLet from one of this modules. This is called Auto-Loading and it's a little bit tricky, so only module vendors use this.
2. Then Powershell executes file `$Profile` it it exists. If you define anything here, it will be executed. If you define function here, It will be executed (for functions this means storing in RAM and be ready to use)

---

So as most easy way, you should create a `$profile` file and paste those functions here:

```
[void][System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($profile))
If (-not [System.IO.File]::Exists($profile)) { '' | Out-File $profile }
Start-Process -Verb 'Edit' -FilePath $profile
```

Comment: I completely misunderstood the concept of a function. Now I do, thanks a lot.